# How to alter table to add a Range Partition

Tags: partitioning

OK Guys, I understand your points... so let me put it this way,

Here is my table
CREATE TABLE TEST1
(
    USERID                 integer,
    ENTRYCREATEDDATE     TIMESTAMP
)  ;

And here is my alter query (I tried adding and removing ADD word below)

ALTER TABLE TEST1 PARTITION BY RANGE (USERID)
( 
    PARTITION P0 VALUES LESS THAN (10)
);

RESULT:
1. Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
01735. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER TABLE option"
*Cause:
*Action:

2. Error report:
   SQL Error: ORA-00902: invalid datatype
3. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
   *Cause:
   *Action:

Now Please help me. Actually I want to partition on ENTRYCREATEDDATE, but will come to that later

Comment: What data type is `userid`?  I'm guessing it's not an integer.  Also, is the above your actual SQL statement?  Because you've misspelled 'partition' as 'partion'.

Comment: @FirebladeDan The `ORA-` error message implies Oracle.

Comment: Spelling mistake was while posting (should have copy-pasted)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it in Teradata:

http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1144_111A/Alter_Function-Syntax.020.106.html

MySQL:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table-partition-operations.html

Oracle:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/alter-table-partition-operations.html

Your google search skills need work sir!

Per your question: Make sure USERID is an INT

Comment: No Sir, that does not help. I have rephrased my query